is there a faster way to solve time interval comparison in pandas?
i am trying to implement a solution that finds consequential alarms for an alarm within the given timeframe. i have created an intervalIndex from the dataframe and used np.vectorize to compare timestamps to the interval index but it is slow for large datasets (350000 rows). is there a way to make this faster, i am not sure how to truly vectorize the operation.
def find_top_consequential_alarms(
    ui: frontPage.Application, data: pd.DataFrame, fromAr: bool
):

    # Get selected alarm and time window based on the source
    selected_alarm = (
        ui.select_conc_alarm.currentText()
        if not fromAr
        else ui.ar_alarm_combo.currentText()
    )
    selected_time = (
        ui.select_conc_time_window.currentText()
        if not fromAr
        else ui.ar_timewindow_combo.currentText()
    )

    # Convert selected time to timedelta
    time_map = {
        "5 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=5),
        "10 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=10),
        "15 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=15),
        "30 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=30),
        "1 Hour": timedelta(hours=1),
        "5 Hours": timedelta(hours=5),
        "24 Hours": timedelta(hours=24),
    }
    time_window = time_map[selected_time]

    # Filter for occurrences of the selected alarm
    specific_alarms = data[data["PtName"].str.strip() == selected_alarm].copy()

    # Create time intervals for each specific alarm occurrence
    specific_alarms["window_start"] = specific_alarms["TimestampUTC"]
    specific_alarms["window_end"] = specific_alarms["TimestampUTC"] + time_window
    intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
        specific_alarms["window_start"], specific_alarms["window_end"], closed="right"
    )

    # Filter for other alarms that fall within any of the intervals
    other_alarms = data[data["PtName"] != selected_alarm].copy()
    in_interval = np.vectorize(lambda x: intervals.contains(x).any(), otypes=[bool])
    mask = in_interval(other_alarms["TimestampUTC"])
    consequential_alarms = other_alarms[mask]

    # Count the occurrences of each alarm within the time windows and get the top 10
    consequential_alarm_counts = consequential_alarms["PtName"].value_counts().head(10)

    title = f"Top 10 Consequential Alarms for {selected_alarm}\n(Time Window: {time_window})"
    return consequential_alarm_counts, title

the overall function is above
# Filter for other alarms that fall within any of the intervals
other_alarms = data[data["PtName"] != selected_alarm].copy()
in_interval = np.vectorize(lambda x: intervals.contains(x).any(), otypes=[bool])
mask = in_interval(other_alarms["TimestampUTC"])
consequential_alarms = other_alarms[mask]

this is the part where that needs improvements.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Faster how? How long does this take with your current solution?

I might have not understood your problem well, but if I did: Find first consequential alarm by using binary search (I assume your alarms are sorted by time). Then iterate all next alarms and stop when you hit alarm out of scope. If this is not what you need, try to fix a bit your explanation please

the function takes about 5-7 seconds for 350,000 rows which is a very small dataset actually, the real data would be around millions. i tried the merge_asof answer below and that took about 0.02 seconds so i think that is the correct way of solving this problem.

np.vectorize works row-by-row, making it slow for large datasets. Instead use pd.merge_asof, which performs highly efficient, vectorized operations for time-based data alignment.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import time

np.random.seed(42)
num_rows = 350000

timestamps = pd.date_range(start="2024-11-01", end="2024-11-10", freq="1min")
random_timestamps = np.random.choice(timestamps, num_rows)
alarm_names = [f"Alarm{np.random.randint(1, 100)}" for _ in range(num_rows)]

data = pd.DataFrame({"PtName": alarm_names, "TimestampUTC": random_timestamps})
def find_top_consequential_alarms(ui, data, fromAr):
    selected_alarm = ui.select_conc_alarm.currentText() if not fromAr else ui.ar_alarm_combo.currentText()
    selected_time = ui.select_conc_time_window.currentText() if not fromAr else ui.ar_timewindow_combo.currentText()

    time_map = {
        "5 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=5),
        "10 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=10),
        "15 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=15),
        "30 Minutes": timedelta(minutes=30),
        "1 Hour": timedelta(hours=1),
        "5 Hours": timedelta(hours=5),
        "24 Hours": timedelta(hours=24),
    }
    time_window = time_map[selected_time]

    specific_alarms = data[data["PtName"].str.strip() == selected_alarm].copy()
    specific_alarms["window_start"] = specific_alarms["TimestampUTC"]
    specific_alarms["window_end"] = specific_alarms["TimestampUTC"] + time_window
    other_alarms = data[data["PtName"].str.strip() != selected_alarm].copy()
    specific_alarms = specific_alarms.sort_values(by="window_start")
    other_alarms = other_alarms.sort_values(by="TimestampUTC")

    start_time = time.time()
    matched_alarms = pd.merge_asof(
        other_alarms,
        specific_alarms,
        left_on="TimestampUTC",
        right_on="window_start",
        direction="backward",
        tolerance=time_window
    )
    execution_time = time.time() - start_time

    consequential_alarms = matched_alarms.dropna(subset=["window_start"])
    consequential_alarm_counts = consequential_alarms["PtName_x"].value_counts().head(10)
    title = f"Top 10 Consequential Alarms for {selected_alarm}\n(Time Window: {time_window})"
    return consequential_alarm_counts, title, execution_time

result_counts, result_title, execution_time = find_top_consequential_alarms(ui, data, fromAr=False)

print(result_counts)
print(result_title)
print(f"Execution Time: {execution_time} seconds")




Which gives you
PtName_x
Alarm19    2954
Alarm36    2951
Alarm41    2951
Alarm31    2939
Alarm15    2933
Alarm75    2932
Alarm83    2932
Alarm40    2932
Alarm88    2927
Alarm54    2927
Name: count, dtype: int64
Top 10 Consequential Alarms for Alarm1
(Time Window: 0:05:00)
Execution Time: 0.022200584411621094 seconds

As you can see, the execution is quite low on a dataframe of 350 000 rows.

okay so i tried this solution and it's really fast. can you give a brief explanation on how merge_asof works here?
